# Cannot compile Flash with Amethyst IDE for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, flash

I create their basic Flash app with their Flash IDE for Visual Studio 2010
http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Products/amethyst-ide/article/amethyst-product-page

When launching the run button, it launch flash but with this error within Flash CS4:

```
The following JavaScript error(s) occurred:
At line 6 of file "FlashApplication1.jsfl":
Cannot find file file:///C:/temp/FlashApplication1/FlashApplication1/FlashApplication1.as.
```

Did someone tried and has this problem also and then a solution ?

Comment: If looks like the either FlashApplication1.as does not exist or it is in a different location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed in a thread in the SapphireSteel Software forum: http://sapphiresteel.com/forum/index.php?topic=542.0